# How can I put one of csv data into variable using node.js cdv-parser?

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm trying to extract data from `CSV` using `node.js`'s `csv-parser`.

The result of `readGreetingData` is that:

- expected : `return = 'Good night'`
- actual :   `return =  blank`

The problem is that:

- `const response` is displayed at `parser.on('end', () => {` method.
- But after escaping the method,  `const response` becomes blank.

How can I improve this function?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv');

const path = require('path');
const filename = '../data/greeting.csv';
const greetingPath = path.join(__dirname, filename);

module.exports = class greeting {
  constructor() {
    this.whatTime = 'midnight';
    this.greetingPattern = this.readGreetingData(this.whatTime);
    console.log('this.greetingPattern= ' + this.greetingPattern);
  }


  //@param: whatTime --> 'midnight'
    readGreetingData(whatTime) {
    const parser = csv.parse({ columns: true });
    const readableStream = fs.createReadStream(greetingPath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    readableStream.pipe(parser);

    const response = [];
    let result = '';
    let data;

    parser.on('readable', () => {
      while (data = parser.read()) {
      }
    });

    parser.on('data', (data) => {
      while (data = parser.read()) {
        if (data['Time'] === whatTime) {
          response.push(data.Greeting);
          break;
        }
      }
    });

    parser.on('end', () => {
     result = response[0];
     console.log(result);
     return result;
    });

    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

CSV is like below.

```
"No","Time","Greeting"
"1","midnight","Good night"
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to this problem, you could use an async/await pattern for this, however, as long as the file is not massive, it may be simpler to use the synchronous API for your needs (async constructors aren't a great idea IMHO).

So you can accomplish what you need like so:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv/lib/sync');
const path = require('path');
const filename = '../data/greeting.csv';
const greetingPath = path.join(__dirname, filename);

module.exports = class greeting {

    constructor() {
        this.whatTime = 'midnight';
        this.greetingPattern = this.readGreetingData(this.whatTime);
        console.log('this.greetingPattern = ' + this.greetingPattern);
    }

    readGreetingData(whatTime) {
        const records = csv.parse(fs.readFileSync(greetingPath), { columns: true });
        const result = records.find(record => record.Time === whatTime);
        return (result || {} ).Greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question kindly. I've tried above code, but it seems a message like: `TypeError: records.find is not a function` was displayed. Could you tell me how I can fix this message? In addition to that, I think my understanding of node.js is insufficient... Could you share good books, documents, or urls if you know?

Comment: Hi @Yoshi, thank you for testing my code.. I'm sure we can resolve that error. Can you just ensure you are using const csv = require('csv/lib/sync'); instead of require('csv'), the interfaces are different! There are some great guides to Node.js on, W3Schools has one: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/, also the official docs: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/. Also: https://blog.codeship.com/node-js-tutorial/. If I can give you my advice, the biggest issue for devs learning Node.js is the asynchronous nature of the language. Once you can understand that you will love it!

Comment: Hi @Terry! It finally worked!!! I really appreciate it. And thank you for giving a lot of useful information. I'll learn hard using your information. For now, I start with understanding differences between asynchronous and synchronous nature of JS. One day, I'd like to be a developer like you! Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey @Yoshi, no problem, good luck with your learning! If I can give another piece of advice: Learn every day and you'll keep getting better. I've never stopped learning and (hopefully) never will!